# Json Parsing Error with Laravel

Tags: php, json, laravel

I want to get json from url but when i try the dd($data) i got parse error on line 1: bla bla expect string error.

First, i doubted with my json object is invalid then i tried with jsontest object but i got still same error.
Here is the simple code:

```
    $stationData = file_get_contents("http://ip.jsontest.com/");
    $stationData = json_decode($stationData);
    dd($stationData);
```

And, this is the error message:

```
Error: Parse error on line 1:
{#149 ▼  +"ip": "95.
-^
Expecting 'STRING', '}'
```

If i use json_decode($data, true)  i got valid array instead of json object.

What's wrong with this?

Comment: what happens when you do `print_r` for example `print_r($stationData->ip);` instead of `dd($stationData)`?

Comment: I've executed your code just right now? And no errors occurred. My output `{#144 ▼
  +"ip": "104.155.78.120"
}`

Comment: @huuuk executed with laravel?

Comment: Yes. I think there are an error in other place of your code.

Comment: There is no code other than.. interesting, maybe its about apache error, i will try with remote right now

Comment: @huuk interesting, i got error with remote too... :/

Comment: try `var_dump` instead of `dd`

Comment: Your code works fine for me, too. Using Laravel. @yigitozmen

Comment: hmm, your error message looks like form js console

Comment: @huuk, i changed os and ran vagrant then executed code but i got still same error...

Comment: http://puu.sh/p9f46/6b8289249f.png

Comment: it seems that error occurs in your browser do you use firebug?

Comment: Your error come from the plugin you use to decode json on your browser, nothing to do with Laravel... Try return json_decode instead of dd()

Comment: alright, @PeterPan666 is right, thanks for help

Comment: Thanks all for helping, how can i mark this solved?

Comment: Reply to your own question and mark it as solved ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As huuk and PeterPan666 said  this is not laravel error. I was using jsonformatter plugin with my chrome, error was coming from plugin.
It solved. Thanks for helping.

Comment: Same issue I am facing from last 2 days and finally your answer helps me to resolve the issue.. thanks man :)